# How do I play music using the system.musicplayer() after the stock Music app has been terminated?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

So I'm making a music player using `system.musicplayer()` since `ipod.musicplayer()` was deprecated with iOS 8. Anyway, I have pause and play buttons that work perfectly when the stock music app is open in the background but not when it is terminated (i.e. removed from multitasking). Before adding the `if`condition, the app would crash, and now nothing happens at all since I don't really know what to add. Any advice? I am truly lost.

```
@IBAction func playButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

       if let mediaItem = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
        if (self.isPlay) {
            musicPlayer.pause()
            self.isPlay = false
        } else {
            musicPlayer.play()
            self.isPlay = true
            setupCurrentMediaItem()
            handleShuffleAndReplayMode()
        }

       } else {
            //music
        }

    }
```

Comment: just a fyi deprecated doesn't mean the feature is gone. All it means is sometime in future it may not be available (dependent upon apple). Some apis's that had been deprecated in ISO 3 are still available and work in iOS 8.

Comment: @SamB better safe than sorry 